# Finding the preimage

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I want to find the preimage of $]-2,4]$ for the function $f(x)=x^2-x$

This is what I have done so far:

We have $0=x^2-x-y$ and therefore the inverse is:

$$f^{-1}(y)=\frac{-1\pm \sqrt{1+4y}}{2}$$

And how do I find out the boundaries of the preimage? If I put the boundaries $-2$ and $4$ into the function $f^{-1}$, I will probably not get them. Also I'm not sure which function I have to take when, the one with plus sign or the one with a minus?

Comment: It is always a good idea to graph $f$ out (with completing the square)...you are in fact just asked to solve $f(x) = x^2 - x \leq 4$!

Comment: Try to think when can you possibly find an inverse. The $\pm$ sign there is a consequence of not being 1-1 and your $f^{-1}$ formula fails at the "boundary" $-2$ is a consequence of not being surjective. In particular, $-2 \notin f(\Bbb{R})$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$f(x) = x^2-x=x^2-x+\frac14-\frac14 = (x-1)^2 - \frac14 \geq -\frac14 $$
you are asked to find $x$ such that $-2\leq f(x) \leq 4$, but $f \geq -\frac14$ so the first inequality doesn't restrict us at any way.

$$ f(x) \leq 4 \Rightarrow (x-1)^2 -\frac14 \leq 4 \Rightarrow (x-1)^2 \leq \frac{17}4\Rightarrow$$
$$ -\frac{\sqrt{17}}{4} \leq x-1 \leq \frac{\sqrt{17}}{4} $$
$$ 1-\frac{\sqrt{17}}{4} \leq x \leq 1+\frac{\sqrt{17}}{4} $$

Comment: Good, but $]-2, 4]$ means $-2 < x \le 4$, though irrelevant here.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this notation, I am with $(-2,4]$. I thought the ] is just a typo and he meant [

Comment: It's less common but [it's a thing](http://www.mathwords.com/i/interval_notation.htm).

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I would do is graph y= x^2- x.  That is a parabola crossing the x-axis at x= 0 and x= 1 and vertex (1/2, -1/4). That does not go down to -2 so this is the same as the pre-image of [-1/4, 4].  But looking at the graph, it is easy to see that the condition is that f(x) be less than 4.  Solving $x^2- x= 4$ we get $x= \frac{1\pm\sqrt{17}}{2}$.  The pre-image is $]\frac{1- \sqrt{17}}{2}, \frac{1+ \sqrt{17}}{2}[$